# GlobalContext.Properties doesn't work although XMLConfigurator.Configure is called afterwards

Tags: c#, logging, configuration, log4net

I set a global property in my log4net appender, where I want to get the current path of the exe as the path for the logfile.

This is my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="%property{LogFileName}.log"/>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

So here I have set my property to `%property{LogFileName}.log`

This is the snippet, where I set this property in my script:

```
        var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

        GlobalContext.Properties["LogFileName"] = directory + "/AccesDBReader"; //log file path
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

I set the `XMLConfigurator.Configure()` after setting the property, so I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to specify the value of the `file` setting should look like below.

Notice the `file` tag being used instead of `param`
and the inclusion of the `type="log4net.Util.PatternString"` specifier.

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFileName}.log" />
```